# Float something left, and center next to it

Tags: html, css

Maybe this is a very stupid question, but I really have no idea.
I want to achieve the following

```
-----------------------------------------
| TEXT LEFT   CENTERED TEXT             |
-----------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| TEXT LEFT                        CENTERED TEXT                                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------
| TEXT   CENTERED TEXT        |
| LEFT                        |
-------------------------------
```

so I want something floated to left, and to center, but the "text left" pushes a bit right the centered text.
I tried two things, both in the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/MeGZ6/

```
<div style="text-align: center; width: 50%; background-color: red;">
<div style="float: left;">left text;</div>
    centered text
</div>
<hr>
    another attempt:
<hr>
<div style="width: 50%; background-color: yellow;">
    <div style="position: absolute; text-align: center;">centered text</div>
text left
</div>
```

the first one obviously not OK. The second, I cant align text inside the div, and it goes on the other text, instead of linebreak it.

EDIT:
this is what I want to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/saLaP/

```
<table style="background-color: red;" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="20%" style="background-color: yellow;">left text</td>
        <td width="60%" style="text-align: center;">centered text</td>
        <td width="20%" style="background-color: green;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the green column is not needed, its just a "helper". Of course, there is no width for any columns, they supposed to be as width as their content

Answer (score 2):

Set `left:0;right:0;` to the absolute positioned div

```
<div style="text-align: center; width: 50%; background-color: red;">
<div style="float: left;">left text;</div>
    centered text
</div>
<hr>
    another attempt:
<hr>
<div style="width: 50%; background-color: yellow;">
    <div style="position: absolute; text-align: center;left:0;right:0;">centered text</div>
text left
</div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/MeGZ6/1/)

Comment: yea, right, but if you shrink the area, it still wont cause linebreak, the text goes over the other. I dont think it can be solved with "position: absolute" way

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that may work for you:

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MeGZ6/2/)**

You just give the container div `text-align: center` and float the other div left. Since the container is 100% of the width and the text is inline, it will auto center.

HTML / CSS:

```
<div style="width: 100%;text-align: center; background-color: yellow;">
    <div style="float: left;">left text</div>
    centered text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the parent div `position: relative` and the center div into `position: absolute`. http://jsfiddle.net/MeGZ6/4/

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left">left text</div>
    <div class="center">centered text</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent{
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: red;
}

.left{
    float: left;
}

.center{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The problem with this is that, if the left div is too long, it will cross the center div. But you can give the left div a `width`, so that it won't cross the center div.

Comment: well, this could be the solution, but there is still no linebreak

Comment: you have to give the left div a width

Comment: and if they were images? So, no width, and expand at the same line?

Comment: what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I might havent give enough instructions. This is what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/saLaP/

```
<table style="background-color: red;" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="20%" style="background-color: yellow;">left text</td>
        <td width="60%" style="text-align: center;">centered text</td>
        <td width="20%" style="background-color: green;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the green column is not needed, its just a "helper".
Of course, there is no width for any columns, they supposed to be as width as their content